# Automatically fitting the text container to text in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

How can I have the text container automatically fit to the text entered in to it?

For example, if I have a text container with a word like 'dog' in it, I have to use the handles to resize the text container manually. This gets tedious on large numbers of text containers. I'd like to have the text container automatically fit to the word 'dog' after I've finished typing.

Answer (score 2):

Open the shape's shapesheet and:

1. Resizing shape's width with text:
   Set cell Width = GUARD(TEXTWIDTH(TheText))
2. Resizing shape's width with text, but with a minimum size (10mm in this case):
   Set cell Width = GUARD(MAX(TEXTWIDTH(TheText), 10mm))

---

Screenshots:

1) Open the shape's shapesheet:

[image]

2) Change the shape's width:

[image]

Comment: Also works in Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional.

Comment: Should work with every version of Visio up to the latest version.